# How to minimize ICQ to tray?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area, icq

How to configure ICQ 7.2 that after closing ICQ window it is minimized to tray?

Now it is minimized to task bar.

OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run the program in compatability mode for Windows Vista. This will cause it to minimise to the tray when pressing the 'x' button to close.

If you right click the application in the start menu, select properties and then the compatability tab you will find the dropdown to change this setting.

This also works for Windows Live Messenger

Comment: ohhh, no!! icq and win7 play crazy games!!